# Как грамотно для ПС реализовать редиректы при переносе сайта на другую платформу?

Tags: wordpress, оптимизация, redirect, поисковые-системы

Есть старый новостной сайт (возраст 5 лет), с хорошими показателями в ПС:

> Проиндексировано страниц: более 35 тыс. ТИЦ: 650, PR: 4

Сайт работает на **Instantcms**.

По ряду причин **переносим сайт на WordPress.**

Естественно, структуру URL-ссылок от Instantcms сохранить полностью и реализовать на WordPress не получается, отсюда опасность того что что-то вылетит из индекса ПС + снизятся показатели ТИЦ и прочее.

Нужны правильные редиректы для ПС? Имеются следующие проблемы:

1) Ссылка на раздел на старом сайте выглядит так:

```
http://site.ru/articles/articles/vlast
```

А на новом будет выглядеть так:

```
http://site.ru/articles/vlast
```

2) Пагинация внутри раздела старого сайта:

```
http://site.ru/articles/articles/vlast?page=2
```

на новом:

```
http://site.ru/articles/vlast/page/2
```

3) Ссылка на отдельную новость (страницу новости) на старом сайте:

```
http://site.ru/articles/articles/politic/byvshii-myer.html
```

на новом:

```
http://site.ru/articles/politic/byvshii-myer.html
```

p.s.: Основная проблема в том что WordPress не поддерживает создание рубрик с одинаковым alias'ом (slug) для ЧПУ, а так бы воссоздали на новом сайте всю необходимую структуру!

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую делать так, как як переносил на одном из проектов:

- Установить Yoast SEO
- Включить дополнительные настройки, что дас твозможность вводить для каждого поста для SEO Title, Desctription, Keywords, Slug и Т.Д.
- Екпорстировать из старого сайта сылки и данные, если не возможно можно использывать написание скрипта для генерации данных, (я писал скрипт, котрый переходыт по URL из xml файла и генерирует мне дополнительный xml с метаданными)
- Написать срипт для Yoast SEO, котрый автоматически добавляет данные в БД к постам